# Is there a way to change this list comprehension to normal loop

Tags: python-3.x

Is there anyway to change this list comprehension to normal for loop representation.

```
result=[[]]
result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in sublist]
```

Edit:

Here is the full code, which i am trying to understand using loops.

```
result = [[]]
mainlist = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3)]
print(mainlist)
  for sublist in mainlist:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in sublist]
  print(result)
```

Output(result):

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: sublist is not defined, so I am not sure what you expect?

Comment: @Andreas I suppose a `for x in range(0,1): raise NameError` will do nicely then? :)

Comment: @Brian I am sorry, but I don't undestand what you are trying to say. Is my comment wrong? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Andreas There's nothing wrong with your comment. I was only adding some humor, hence the `:)`.

Comment: @Brian ah! You got me, I thought it was sarcastic. xD

Comment: @Andreas Here i have made some changes in question by adding the Complete code and the output which it is producing.

Comment: You produce a list based on `result`, assign that to `result`, and go back to loop again. The machine is doing what you told it to. It's not clear that's what you want. The question you asked was about turning comprehension into an explicit loop, and you now have such an answer.

Comment: @J_H I am trying the understand how a for loop will work in the same way this list comprehension is working by giving the output as stated above. So how can i change the list comprehension into for loop to get the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be `out`.

```
x = []  # OP was assigning this constant expression to x.
out = []
for y in sublist:
    out.append(x + [y])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have made some changes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because it is essentially not a list comprehension on its own but a for-loop combined with a list comprehension.

```
result = [[]]
mainlist = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3)]

for sublist in mainlist:
    out = []
    for x in result:
        for y in sublist:
            out.append(x+[y])
    result = out
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have made some changes in the question.

Comment: Ok. I thought maybe you were worried about subsequent code changing `out` and thereby unintentionally messing with `result` :-)